# PHPUnit isn't installed properly

Tags: phpunit

I was trying to use PHPUnit through eclipse helios but everytime it says "Could not open input file: .\pear\PHPUnit2\TextUI\TestRunner.php"

I did uninstall and install PHPUnit but also its not working.

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit2 is an ancient version that is not used anymore. The current PHPUnit major version is 3, and it does not have the "2" in the file paths anymore.

Set your Eclipse to use PHPUnit3, not PHPUnit2.